# Throttling individual samba connections

Tags: samba, qos, bandwidth-control

I have a CentOS server set up with Samba on a gigabit LAN connection.  I've found that if I copy large amounts of data from the Samba server to a client machine that also has a gigabit connection, that one file copy process completely eats up Samba's attention.  Sometimes I can't even get a share listing on another computer while the copy is going.

Is there a way to set up some sort of QoS on Samba so that multiple clients are forced to share the bandwidth/whatever-samba-is-limited-on and be nice to each other?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this within Samba - That said, go lower in layer to TCP/IP and you can classify your packets all day long.  you can do this with iptables and CLASSIFY (I think).  I personally have used wondershaper and shaper (no longer a package in Debian) to accomplish this.

Here is a QoS article from the Debian Admin handbook:

http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.quality-of-service.html

Here's an article using iptables:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.fullnat.intro.html

Comment: This is a topic I have never approached before, so forgive me if my question isn't intelligent.  Doing some reading, it looks like these articles are about limiting traffic for a specific service as a whole (e.g., Samba only gets 10 MBps total bandwidth).  I need to limit the traffic on individual connections to a single service (e.g., Bob can't use Samba's whole 10 MBps since Suzy wants to connect to Samba too).  Do these concepts apply to that as well?